# PIVOT in HSQLDB

Tags: pivot, hsqldb

I want to insert 1 million records in CLIENT side HSQLDB and i want to perform pivoting operation with that one

million records in client side to analyze the business growth in various ways.

Is there HSQLDB having this feature. If so kindly help me.

Answer (score 3):

In general pivoting operations are implemented with aggregate functions together with CASE WHEN and GROUP BY.

HSQLDB has all the features of PostgreSQL and MySQL that are used for operating pivots. You can look at questions with the PIVOT tag on stackoverflow for examples.

I will add the PIVOT tag to this question.